# Saving a Bitmap

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

I am following a tutorial on saving bitmaps. It has gone well, but I am having a problem now. The program does compile successfully. It can save the file, but when I open the file it says:

Windows Live Photo Gallery:

> Photo Gallery can't open this photo or video. The file may be
>   unsupported, damaged or corrupt.

Here are some pieces of the code:
Call to the functions in WndProc():

```
case SAVE_BM:
{
    BOOL result = SaveFileDlg(hwnd, filePath, "Save Bitmap");
    if (result)
    {
        PBITMAPINFO pbi = CreateBmpInfoStruct(hwnd, hBitmap);
        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        SaveBmpFile(hwnd, filePath, pbi, hBitmap, hdc);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

SaveBmpFile():

```
void SaveBmpFile(HWND hwnd, LPSTR file, PBITMAPINFO pbi, HBITMAP hBMP, HDC hDC)
{
    std::ofstream hF;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;
    PBITMAPINFOHEADER pbmih;
    LPBYTE bits;
    DWORD total;
    DWORD cB;
    BYTE *hP;
    pbmih = (PBITMAPINFOHEADER) pbi;
    bits = (LPBYTE) GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, pbmih->biSizeImage);
    if (!bits)
        MessageBox(hwnd, "GlobalAlloc()", "Error", MB_OK);
    if (!GetDIBits(hDC, hBMP, 0, (WORD) pbmih->biHeight, bits, pbi, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
        MessageBox(hwnd, "GetDIBits()", "Error", MB_OK);
    hF.open(file, std::ios::binary);
    if (hF.fail())
        MessageBox(hwnd, "open()", "Error", MB_OK);
    bmfh.bfType = 0x4d42;
    bmfh.bfSize = (DWORD) (sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + pbmih->biSize + pbmih->biClrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD) + pbmih->biSizeImage);
    bmfh.bfReserved1 = 0;
    bmfh.bfReserved2 = 0;
    bmfh.bfOffBits = (DWORD) sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + pbmih->biSize + pbmih->biClrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD);
    hF.write((char*) &bmfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    if (hF.fail())
        MessageBox(hwnd, "write() file header", "Error", MB_OK);
    hF.write((char*) pbmih, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + pbmih->biClrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD));
    if (hF.fail())
        MessageBox(hwnd, "write() info header", "Error", MB_OK);
    total = cB = pbmih->biSizeImage;
    hP = bits;
    hF.write((char*) hP, (int) cB);
    if (hF.fail())
        MessageBox(hwnd, "write() data", "Error", MB_OK);
    hF.close();
    if (hF.fail())
        MessageBox(hwnd, "close()", "Error", MB_OK);
    GlobalFree((HGLOBAL) bits);
}
```

SaveBmpInfoStruct():

```
PBITMAPINFO CreateBmpInfoStruct(HWND hwnd, HBITMAP hBMP)
{
    BITMAP BMP;
    PBITMAPINFO pbmi;
    WORD clrBits;
    if (!GetObject(hBMP, sizeof(BITMAP), (LPSTR) &BMP))
        MessageBox(hwnd, "GetObject()", "Error", MB_OK);
    clrBits = (WORD) (BMP.bmPlanes * BMP.bmBitsPixel);
    if (clrBits == 1)
        clrBits = 1;
    else if (clrBits <= 4)
        clrBits = 4;
    else if (clrBits <= 8)
        clrBits = 8;
    else if (clrBits <= 16)
        clrBits = 16;
    else if (clrBits <= 24)
        clrBits = 24;
    else
        clrBits = 32;
    if (clrBits != 24)
        pbmi = (PBITMAPINFO) LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * (1<< clrBits));
    else
        pbmi = (PBITMAPINFO) LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth = BMP.bmWidth;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight = BMP.bmHeight;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = BMP.bmPlanes;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = BMP.bmBitsPixel;
    if (clrBits < 24)
        pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = (1<< clrBits);
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = ((pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth * clrBits + 31) & ~31) / 8 * pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    return pbmi;
    }
```

SaveFileDlg():

```
BOOL SaveFileDlg(HWND hwnd, LPSTR fileName, LPSTR titleName)
{
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    ofn.lpstrCustomFilter = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxCustFilter = 0;
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 0;
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFile = fileName;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = titleName;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "Bitmap Files (*.bmp)\0*.bmp\0\0";
    ofn.lpstrTitle = titleName;
    return GetSaveFileName(&ofn);
}
```

Let me know if you need to see more code.
I have searched Google a few times, but I have not found anything.  It is a little hard to find something for this exact condition.  I have tried this on another forum, but it has not worked out, as you can tell by me asking this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should only be using `biClrUsed` and storing palette colors if the image bit depth is 8 or less. Currently you're setting `biClrUsed` for a 16 bit image as well, and supplying palette colors for anything other than a 24 bit image (which would mean a 32 bit image will have a 4 billion entry palette table).

Comment: @JonathanPotter So, should I remove everything that is dealing with stuff over 8 bits?

Comment: If you are writing this for the learning experience that's fine. If you need a robust pre-built solution you might want to look into the [Windows Imaging Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx) instead. It offers support for reading and writing a wide variety of digital image formats. Basic COM knowledge is required however.

Comment: @IInspctable I can look into that, but this is the only tutorial I have found that really explained things.

Comment: What should I do with the: if(clrBits != 24) and if(clrBits < 24) ?

Comment: Anyone, please!  I don't mean to sound pushy, but I really need to get this done.  Again, thanks!

Comment: I'd start out simple: just support 32-bit BMPs. When you have that working, you can add the code to pad lines to handle 24- and 16-bit BMPs. Supporting 8-bits (or less) adds quite a bit of extra work for relatively little payoff -- I doubt I'd bother.

Comment: I have gotten this fixed.